# Colormap entire subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-mapping

I'm having some trouble with color maps. Basically, what I would like to produce is similar to the image below.

On the bottom subplot I would like to be able to plot the relevant colour, but spanning the entire background of the subplot.i.e it would just look like a colourmap over the entire plot, with no lines or points plotted. It should still correspond to the colours shown in the scatter plot.

Is it possible to do this? what I would ideally like to do is put this background under the top subplot.  ( the y scales are in diferent units)

[image]

Thanks for and help.

**code** for bottom scatter subplot:

```
x = np.arange(len(wind))
y = wind
t = y
plt.scatter(x, y, c=t)
```

where wind is a 1D array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use imshow to display your wind array. It needs to be reshaped to a 2D array, but the 'height' dimensions can be length 1. Setting the extent to the dimensions of the top axes makes it align with it.

```
wind = np.random.randn(100) + np.random.randn(100).cumsum() * 0.5
x = np.arange(len(wind))
y = wind
t = y

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(10,6))

ax[0].plot(x,y)

ax[1].plot(x, 100- y * 10, lw=2, c='black')

ymin, ymax = ax[1].get_ybound()
xmin, xmax = ax[1].get_xbound()

im = ax[1].imshow(y.reshape(1, y.size), extent=[xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax], interpolation='none', alpha=.5, cmap=plt.cm.RdYlGn_r)
ax[1].set_aspect(ax[0].get_aspect())

cax = fig.add_axes([.95,0.3,0.01,0.4])
cb = plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
cb.set_label('Y parameter [-]')
```

[image]

If you want to use it as a 'background' you should first plot whatever you want. Then grab the extent of the bottom plot and set it as an extent to `imshow`. You can also provide any colormap you want to `imshow` by using `cmap=`.

Comment: thanks, is it possible too use this as a background to another plot(with the same x scale, but different y scale), and put the scale in say a color bar

Comment: also is it possible to set it to a different colormap?

Comment: Great, btw notice how the points in the line graph align with the start of the colored vertical 'bars'. You could shift it to the center by subtracting half an `x-unit` in the extent: `extent=[xmin-.5,xmax-.5,ymin,ymax]`